# Is this a bug in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.NET when I try to add a dynamic control (includes validation) to `Placeholder` or any other control container, the name of control become an important. For example, this is very normal, easy control adding code.

```
var control = LoadControl("TestUserControl.ascx");
control.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
```

as you see, I'm giving guid to control's ID. In Runtime, this code fails, and compiler says this is a javascript error, and error message like ';' character expected, missing.. etc..

The problem is very interesting. Dynamically added ASP.NET control (includes validation), causes an error because of " - " character in dynamically named ID property (or anything like '-', '.',etc..).

When I refine my code like:

```
var control = LoadControl("TestUserControl.ascx");
control.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
```

problem goes away :)

Is this a bug in **ASP.NET 3.5**? Why its look like a javascript error in page?

Comment: Can't really understand to why you'd want to set the Id to a NewGuid, Why just not leave it blank? asp.net will generate a server id for you..   you COULD use "Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") also... if you want to skip the "dashes"

Comment: I need to set ID, because the control includes validation. NewGuid() is sample ID. Summary, the ID includes special characters, causes a missing character javascript error.

Comment: @ullmark I think you didn't understand my question exactly. Problem is not Guid, problem is special character exception, causes a Javascript exception in runtime. Thats what I found interesting, and thought is it a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug so much as misuse. You couldn't give a control an ID that included a `-` if you did it within the IDE, so it makes sense that attempting to do it dynamically should have unintended results. The math functions are riddled with peculiarities like this that aren't bugs. Sure MS probably could have put in a function in the property that checked for invalid characters in the ID before allowing it to be set, but that would be a runtime error anyway (which is what you have).

Comment: Yes, it is a runtime error, and appears like JavaScript error. This is the interesting...

Comment: @Serkan Hekimoglu - a little I suppose. There are many runtime errors that end up appearing like JS errors though, mostly because they produce some invalid nonsense in the ViewState or some of the other built-in JS. I still wouldn't classify it as a bug. At best I'd say it's an improperly thrown exception. My expectation is that the control would have some sort of validation on the ID field that would thrown a .Net exception at runtime, so maybe it could be considered a design oversight.