# ASP.NET dynamic controls and validators - Unable to find control id '...' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of '...'

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

I have seem many forum posts / responses on this subject but I am no closer to a solution.

I am loading a repeating data structure from the DB into UpdatePanel controls in an event handler. The number of repeats varies so controls are all created and added to a container panel dynamically. The user has the ability to edit the data so I am also dynamically creating validator controls (`RegularExpressionValidator`s)

The problem is in setting the ControlToValidate property of the validator. No matter how I set this I get the `Unable to find control id '...' referenced by the 'ControlToValidate' property of '...'` error response from the server which is then raised by ASP.NET AJAX JS.

The short version of the control adding code looks like this:

```
TextBox licenseCode = new TextBox();
licenseCode.ID = this.getNextId();  // generated ID contains only [A-Za-Z], [0-9], :, -, .
licenseCode.MaxLength = 50;
this.purchaseEdit.Controls.Add(licenseCode);  // this.purchaseEdit is an asp:Panel

RegularExpressionValidator licenseCodeVal = new RegularExpressionValidator();
licenseCodeVal.ControlToValidate = licenseCode.ClientID;
licenseCodeVal.ID = this.getNextId();
licenseCodeVal.ValidationGroup = this.purchaseEditSave.ValidationGroup;  // save button within the panel
licenseCodeVal.ValidationExpression = @"^.{1," + licenseCode.MaxLength.ToString() + "}$";
licenseCodeVal.ErrorMessage = "Between 1 and " + licenseCode.MaxLength.ToString() + " chars.";
this.purchaseEdit.Controls.Add(licenseCodeVal);
```

As you can see both controls are added to the same container, the validator is added after the TextBox, and the ControlToValidate property is currently set to the ClientID of the TextBox. I have tried the ID value too but no joy.

The really irritating thing is that if I don't add the validator, and using a breakpoint inspect the ClientID of the TextBox, I can inspect the DOM of the updated page and find the ID attribute of the TextBox:

```
<input type="text" id="ctl00_ContentBody_PCTL::4890cc3a-8d07-4dee-aa9f-bdd8735fcaf8::licCode"... />
```

As far as I can tell I'm not doing anything wrong, so why am I getting this error??

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Since you are at the server side, why are you referencing the control to validate using its client id instead of a server id?

Comment: As I said above, I've tried both and neither work. The only difference when using the server ID is that the 'missing' ID in the JS error is not prefixed by ct100...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARGH so I finally figured this thing out - it came down to special characters in the ID. I was having an issue with a JQuery selector which contained ':' and figured I should just check if that was causing the validator issues - it was.

In the end I created my GUIDs without any hyphens and replaced ':' with '_' and the problem went away. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968823/is-this-a-bug-in-asp-net-3-5) helped.

<strike>I haven't seen anything from MSDN saying certain characters are not permitted in IDs, but then I tend to refer to MSDN with specific problems after jumping in, so maybe there is something on there.</strike>. See comment below

Comment: >>I haven't seen anything from MSDN saying certain characters are not permitted in IDs
From MSDN `Control.ID`: "Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error."

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `ClientID` but the `ID` of the TextBox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate.aspx

> "I have tried the ID value too but no joy."

But you didn't get an exception and only the validation didn't work?!

My suggestion is to wrap the control and the validator in an `UserControl` and add this dynamically to your container-control. On this way you can use fix ID's because they all have distinct `NamingContainers`.

The code will be cleaner. Encapsulation also increases reusability.

Comment: ID instead of ClientID throws the same error but just without the ct100... prefix. On your suggestion I see what you're getting at but the control IDs are used in other areas and this would mean a significant change - not a huge issue in itself but I don't really see how it could fix my problem: in both my current and your suggested scenarios I have a validator referencing an ID that *does* exist in the same container.

Comment: You have provides too less information. 1) What does `getNextId()` generate for IDs. Show the function. 2) Where and when are you creating the controls? Are you recreating them on *every* postback with exactly the *same ID* as before? Normally it would be sufficient to use a counter that you store in a ViewState variable to get/set the number of created controls so that you can recreate them in Page_Init or at last in Page_Load(events are too late).

Comment: thanks for sticking with me :) 1) I provided an example above of an ID - PCTL::4890cc3a-8d07-4dee-aa9f-bdd8735fcaf8::licCode - built with a constant prefix, suffix, separator and a new GUID. 2) The UpdatePanel posts following a button click, in the handler I get DB data and loop through, creating a set of controls and validators for each entry. The ID changes each post but a common ID always joins a TextBox and its validator. Are you saying the event handler is too late to create a validator? Please note my TextBox is created just fine (from the handler) when I comment out the validator.

Comment: @tomfumb: sorry, cannot stick longer ;)
But please read my last comment again carefully. What is the contradiction between my "**recreating them on every postback with exactly the same ID as before**" and your **GUID**?! They are the exact opposite, unique on the whole server and different on every postback. Why do you need them? It'll be impossible to get the `TextBox.Text` on postbacks or handle their `TextChanged` event not sure about your `ControlToValidate`-issue(but sure that you need the ID instead of the ClientID).

Comment: The event-handler is not too late to create additional controls but it's too late to recreate the old dynamic controls. You can add controls till Page_PreRender and ensure that their values will be stored in ViewState, but ViewState is loaded until Page_Load, therefore you neeed to recreate these controls there at latest.

Comment: I already solved the problem of retrieving the data from *partially* unknown IDs following a post - after the GUID each ID ends with some text identifying its type (i.e. which element of data it represents). As there are an unknown number of controls and new controls can be added each post the IDs cannot stay the same. Only the input and its validator need to share any knowledge of the full ID. Anyway, I eventually solved the issue but removing special characters from the ID, and yes I did need the ID instead of ClientID. Thanks for the suggestions.